# Override POST value from user form before update with if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that's working perfectly:

```
def update 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Blog post updated.'
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render("edit")  
  end     
end
```

But if the user leaves a form blank before submit, I then want to pass in a variable.  Otherwise the user submitted value is stored.  I can't quite get the syntax right, I need something like this:

```
def update 
  if params[:permalink] == nil
    params[:permalink] = "#{defaultValue}"
  end
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Blog post updated.'
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render("edit")  
  end     
end
```

The code doesn't seem to grab onto the `params[:permalink]` before save when there is in fact a :permalink field in the form.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `params[:permalink]` is most probably an empty string and not nil.  try changing the whole if block with `params[:permalink] = params[:permalink].presence || defaultValue`

Comment: Since you are trying to save `post_params` probably you have `params[:post][:permalink]` and not `params[:permalink]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
def update
  if !params[:post][:permalink].presence
    params[:post][:permalink] = "#{defaultValue}"
  end
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Blog post updated.'
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render("edit")  
  end     
end
```